# The first Anime/Manga with a parody's genre ever created

Tags: tropes

Gintama i would said the The most epic Anime with Parody ever made. Here's some example

**One Piece Parody**

[image]

**Naruto Parody**

[image]

Binbougami Ga anime sure have many episode that contains parody. Ex:

**Dragonball Parody**

[image]

**Hokuto No ken**

[image: strong text]

**Death Note**

[image]

Why this kind of episode became so popular in anime? I know the episode that were made for a parody is a Joke episode to entertain. But What is the first anime Parody that were found in anime hitory ?

Comment: Personally, I think this is a rather silly question. The idea of parody (satire, mockery, caricature, call it what you will) is as old as the idea of narrative. It certainly wasn't invented by anime. Identifying the "first" instance of it in anime (if one even can) seems like a pointless endeavor.

Answer (score 3):

Oldest Manga/Anime that's considered "Parody" I could find is [Sennin Baraku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sennin_Buraku) which started serialization in October 1956 and the 23 episode anime started in 1963.

(From Wikipedia)

> Sennin Buraku takes place in Taoyuan, a small Edo period village, populated solely by Taoist ascetics. The eldest, Lao Shi, conducts research into magic and alchemy, while his disciple Zhi Huang remains more interested in pleasures of the flesh. He has fallen for three pretty sisters who live nearby, much to Lao Shi's annoyance.

No idea why parody is popular, but like most genres, it's probably helped significantly by the general popularity of anime.

Comment: were they mention what parody did they used ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any specifics, though from what I can tell, the show isn't exactly at the level that Gintama is where everything is practically fan service/references to other anime or pop culture.